# Simple mysql update query is sometimes slow

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a simple query that usually is done within 0.0002 seconds. Sometimes (eg. 1 of 200) the query will take up to 1000 times as long to finish.

Slow query log:

```
# Time: 111205 12:21:21
# User@Host: abc[abc] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 0.120205  Lock_time: 0.000025 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1323084081;
UPDATE `users` 
SET `online`=NOW(), 
     lastip='123.123.123.123', 
     pageviews = pageviews + '1', 
     onlinetoday = '1' 
WHERE `user_name`='Alex' 
LIMIT 1;
```

The `user_name` field is indexed. The updated fields (`online`, `lastip`, `pageviews` and `onlinetoday`) are not.

The same problem occurs when using the primary key (**`A_I, int(35)`**) instead of the **`user_name (varchar(50)`**.

The table contains 22 000 rows and 68 fields, 5 of them are indexes.

I also have another table that has the exact same problem:

```
CREATE TABLE `person_values` (
 `id` int(255) NOT NULL,
 `A1` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A2` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A3` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A4` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A5` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A6` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A7` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A8` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A9` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A10` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A11` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A12` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A13` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A14` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A15` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A16` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A17` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A18` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A19` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A20` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A21` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A22` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A23` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A24` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A25` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A26` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A27` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `A28` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 UNIQUE KEY `person` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Query:

```
UPDATE `person_values` SET A25 = A25 + 1 WHERE id = '1' LIMIT 1;
```

Table `person_values` contains about 28 000 rows.

Mysql server version: 5.1.49-3-log
Mysql client version: 5.1.49
Distro: Debian 6.0.3

What can be causing this problem?

Comment: Hi newbie, this is too little information, might to include store engine, version number, platform (windows or linux)

Answer (score 0):

1. please post relevant parts of your schema: `SHOW CREATE TABLE
   tbl_name`.
2. check if you have set the size of the index for user_name,
       as you're most probably using varchar column. You should set the
       length in chars for an index on such a column like: `CREATE INDEX
       part_of_name ON customer (name(10));`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to immediately read back the row you just modified you could try replacing your `UPDATE` statement with a `REPLACE DELAYED` (note: their syntax differs! unfortunately there is no `UPDATE DELAYED`...) and see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this was InnoDB, I would answer: The update is fast when the row is in the buffer pool, otherwise it should be first loaded in the buffer pool, next updated, and finally written back. MyISAM works in similar way, it has to open the table and locate the record, in order to update it. So having a simple query took 0.1 seconds at some times is perfectly acceptable. You can increase the corresponding settings (like how many tables can MySQL keep opened and some buffers if they are used in MyISAM) to make this rarely or never happen.